# GNU sort -u outputs binary characters

Tags: bash, shell, sorting, unix, gnu

I am trying to get all unique values from a column in a very large file (5 columns, 2,044,530,100 lines, ~49 GB). My current approach is to cut the relevant column and putting it through sort -u (which sorts and only outputs the unique values). While my INPUT is just text, my output contains binary characters and makes it unusable.

First lines of INPUT look like this:

```
1 D12 rs01 T T
1 D12 rs02 G G
1 D12 rs03 G G
1 D15 rs01 C C
```

Putting it through a tr command does not make it better, it just makes the binary characters visible.

```
cut -d" " -f3 INPUT | sort -u > OUTPUT
cut -d" " -f3 INPUT | tr -cd '\11\12\15\40-\176' | sort -u > OUTPUT
```

For example, some sample-output from the command above:

```
yO+{(#6:1fr
    EvI0^?E0/':>)zj;<f#V&:oY\RM&mhR!6(qV%|`rJTq4IKqV{]Dzb"~8(X82
    F:7nc9gZ#nht^M">vo|F+g"x%r>UdF+Rn^MOu=
```

While the expected output is a column with all unique values in a value, e.g.:

```
rs01
rs02
rs03
rs04
rs05
```

Unfortunately, I can't replicate this behavior with generated (smaller) data. Does anyone have a suggestion of how to deal with this? All help is greatly appreciated. Sort version is sort (GNU coreutils) 8.4

Comment: what is the output of `head INPUT`?

Comment: I would check the output without sorting first to make sure your input is purely text like you think it is.

Comment: All that shows is that the first four lines are what you expect. It doesn't cover the rest of the file. If you don't sort it where do the incorrect output lines show up? (I will admit some confusion as to how those leading spaces would be in the output though given that leading `cut` command.

Comment: I've added some sample INPUT lines in the question. The thing is, the incorrect lines only show up after the sort. If there is a comprehensive method of finding non-pure text in my INPUT, that would be useful. But, since it's such a large file, just glancing over the file with `less` is not informative.

Comment: Have you check with `strings`, something like `strings INPUT | cut ...` ?

Comment: It might be a memory overflow of `sort`, since `sort` has to keep the whole data into memory to work... there is a `-S` option in `sort` to set the buffer size, you may try it.

Comment: Didn't know about the `strings` command, looks promising, trying that now!

Comment: You can iterate; check the output for the first, say, 100,000 lines. If it looks good, move on to the 100,000 lines. Otherwise, split those into 10,000-line chunks and repeat. Eventually, you should find the part of the input which produces the unexpected output.

Comment: @EdouardThiel That would depend on the implementation. GNU `sort`, for example, will use temporary files for large input sets, with the `-S` option governing how much to buffer in memory at any given time.

Comment: It worths trying `-S`, just to be sure it is not the cause of the issue...

Comment: It's GNU sort, indeed. What would be a recommended buffer size for sort -S?

Comment: Unless it's a truly ancient version of GNU sort, I don't think that's the issue.

Comment: It's coreutils 8.4, which I wouldn't call ancient

Comment: As you have an up-to-date sort AND I assume that there is plenty of free diskspace where sort is writing its work files, then it's hard to see how it can be the sort. So as you used `tr -cd` to find your bad chars, why not just go with `-d` and delete the bad data. If you can't fix it at the source, this seems like what you'll have to do. Good luck and let us know if  you find a better resolution.

Comment: Does it help to keep printable and control chars only: eg `tr -cd '[:print:][:cntrl:]'` or is that equivalent to what you did?

Comment: I think so, I got that `tr` command from [here](http://alvinalexander.com/blog/post/linux-unix/how-remove-non-printable-ascii-characters-file-unix)

Comment: You could try using a really *small* `-S` to force the use of temporary files, maybe you could reproduce the problem with a smaller test case. If this was happening to me I'd be trying to preserve the temp files for inspection after the sort is done. There's no option for that, so I'd do something sneaky: run the test case under `gdb`, break on `unlink` and when it hits, look for `/tmp/sort*`. Wild idea: are the files compressed? GNU sort has a `--compress-program` option. If it's somehow half-enabled, compressing the files but not decompressing them, that'd explain the crazy output.

Comment: The latest tests indicate that indeed the original large inputfile is damaged. Fortunately I got the opportunity to  go back to the original files that were merged to constitute my inputfile, and locate the bad part. Lesson learned: before ever doubting GNU coreutils I should inspect my files very thoroughly.
I expect that fixing my input will make sure that the output of `sort -u` will be ok again. 
Thanks for all the useful comments. I have learned a lot (more) about `tr`, `strings` and `sort`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of manually splitting the file for inspection I would try grep-ing the input file for unusual characters, just to make sure your input is not damaged, or locate the place with garbage.

```
grep -b -E -v -e '^[[:alnum:][:space:]]+$' <your file>
```

If the input is OK, try to use temporary file instead of pipe, and examine it in the same way. If it is OK, blame `sort`.
(PS. I would rather post it as a comment, not a solution but I can't)

Comment: This indeed gave damaged output, confirming that the inputfile was bad to begin with. Although it doesn't rule out that `sort -u` is doing something strange with extremely large files, it does seem unlikely.

Comment: Edit: there wasn't a real answer to this question, other than "_check your input_". I think you provided a very useful command to check input in general, and this was certainly part of the solution _for me_.  So there you go, I mark this answer as the solution.